# VSTO - How to make Ribbon buttons to fill vertically the blank space

Tags: excel, button, vsto, ribbon, fill

I'm building a VSTO excel application, using Visual Studio 2013. I have one Large sized Ribbon button in one column, next to two Regular sized in another column. What I want is to fill the vertical space in the regular buttons column equally.

To see an example of what I want to do, see the "Calculation" group of "FORMULAS" tab in excel. My regular buttons are stacking on the top, but i want them to fill the empty space just like the "Calculate Now" and the "Calculate Sheet" are doing in this ribbon.

How do I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fluent UI doesn't provide any property or attribute for that.

Read more about the Fluent UI (Ribbon UI) in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

Not all features (controls) are available for external developers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you will be able to do this. I was also looking for this but didn't find a solution. The ribbon is limited for programmers in certain features, for example you cannot make a menu with headers (like the insert chart in excel) or in ribbon galleries (like the chart styles),... I think this button fill is also one of these features.